# How to fit two keras ImageDataGenerators for sets of images

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am looking for a solution or an example for the following task:

I have sets of images of the **same objects taken from different angles**.
I would like to build a deep-CNN with keras, which can take **sets** of two images, perform data augmentation on each image separately, and feed them together into a connected model.

*more detailed explanation:*

The images are stored in a HDF5 file, with the following shapes:

```
data['Xp'] # shape=(3000, 224, 224, 3) #RGB images
data['Xs'] # shape=(3000, 224, 224, 3) #RGB images
data['Y']  # shape=(3000, 9) #categorical data.
```

Now, I want a generator that can:

1. scramble the indexes of the data sets.
2. Then take images and
3. categories from  the data augment the images from `X1_train`, `X2_train`
4. separately feed it into a netwrok with the following structure:

The code...

```
from keras.layers import Flatten, Dense, Input, Dropout, Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Merge


img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block1_conv1')(img_input)
x = Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same', name='block1_conv2')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='block1_pool')(x)

# ... more network definition here ....

model1 = Model(img_input, x)
model2 = Model(img_input, x)

merged = Merge([model1, model2], mode='concat')

final_model = Sequential()
final_model.add(merged)
final_model.add(Dense(9, activation='softmax'))
```

I created the following generator that yields the expected data to feed the 
`fit_generator` of the model...

```
def aug_train_iterator(Xp, Xs, Y, database_file=database_file, is_binary=True):
    from itertools import izip
    from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

    seed = 7 #make sure that two iterators give same tomato each time...

    ig = ImageDataGenerator(dim_ordering='tf', rotation_range=90,
                                               width_shift_range=0.05,
                                               height_shift_range=0.05,
                                               zoom_range=0.05,
                                               fill_mode='constant',
                                               cval=0.0,
                                               horizontal_flip=True,
                                               rescale=1./255)


    for batch in izip(ig.flow(Xp,Y,  seed=seed), ig.flow(Xs, seed=seed)):
        for i in range(len(batch[0][0])):
            x1 = batch[0][0][i].reshape(1,224, 224, 3)
            x2 = batch[1][i].reshape(1, 224, 224, 3)
            y = batch[0][1][i].reshape(1,2)
            yield ([x1, x2], y)
```

Now, when I try to fit the model...

```
gen = aug_train_iterator(Xp, Xs, Y)
final_model.fit_generator(gen, 1000, 20)
```

It actually running for a few images... and then raise error about ~ 15 images:

```
Epoch 1/20
  15/1000 [..............................] - ETA: 606s - loss: 0.7001 - acc: 0.4000

Exception in thread Thread-44:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 404, in data_generator_task
    generator_output = next(generator)
  File "<ipython-input-134-f128a127c7ce>", line 35, in aug_train_iterator
    for batch in izip(ig.flow(Xp,Y,  seed=seed), ig.flow(Xs, seed=seed)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 495, in next
    x = self.X[j]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 367, in __getitem__
    if self._local.astype is not None:
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Well, I missed the possible solution in the keras docs... If I will use same seed and keyword arguments to the fit two different generators - it should work. I will test it.

Comment: seems like a issue of h5py, try to update it by `pip install --upgrade h5py`

Comment: Well, using the pickle_safe=True seems to solve this problem. Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

using the pickle_safe=True solved the problem